# Manipulating Excel xls and xlsx in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, excel

We need to update some cells of an Excel file (either xls or xlsx) on an asp.net webpage. The other cells dependent will get updated automatically as well.

We have tried to use: Excel Interop but we have encountered too many problems after developing  on the server: installing office, errors with security and adding more rights to the NETWORK SERVICE, ... sometimes it works. So it is not stable.

We are looking for an open source library for manipulating an excel file (xls or xlsx) on asp.net. Could you please recommend some good ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As you already discovered: Using Interop on the server is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2*

Since Windows Vista MS introduced several security-related measures which prevent a Windows Service from doing "desktop-like" things... which means you would have to circumvent several security measures to get it to work (NOT recommended!).

To deal with Excel files without any need for Office etc. in a server-scenario there are several options (free and commercial) out there:

I can recommend [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)... didn't try [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) but hear+read lots of good things about it...

Free options (though for the newer xlsx format only!) are for example  [OpenXML 2 from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library:

http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to change excel files, it don't need Office Instalation and is more simple than Excel Interop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel-Version greater than 2003, you might find ClosedXML helpful:

https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

Answer (score 0):

We have used http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview and are happy with the possibilities and the performance

Comment: I got an error that it does not understand the structure: Reading error: file is not a valid OLE2 Compound File.